# SharedPreferences value is not updated

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I am trying to update the values of **SharedPreferences**, here is my code:

```
edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
edit.putString(Settings.PREF_USERNAME+"",txtuser);
edit.putString(Settings.PREF_PASSWORD+"",txtpass);
edit.commit();"
```

The problem is that when I am accessing this values, it is not returning updated values, it gives me a value of SharedPreferences.

But when I am confirming the data in **XML** file ,the data updated in that.

And after restarting my application I am getting that updated values. So it requires me to restart the application to get updated values.
So, how to get those updated values once it changes?

Thanks in advance

**Here is my whole code:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ctx=this;

            status=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(Settings.PREF_STATUS, Settings.DEFAULT_STATUS);// get old value
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  on(ctx,true);//  function will call and value is updated

                }
            }});    

     status=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(Settings.PREF_STATUS, Settings.DEFAULT_STATUS);// this should give me a updated value but gives old value

    }
    public static boolean on(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(Settings.PREF_ON, Settings.DEFAULT_ON);
    }

    public static void on(Context context,boolean on) {
            if (on) Receiver.engine(context).isRegistered(); //
        }




**********in reciver file***********
public void isRegistered ) {
        Editor edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Receiver.mContext).edit();
        edit.putString(Settings.PREF_STATUS+"","0");
        edit.commit();
}
```

Comment: show code of getting the value.

Comment: Can you show other code that gives correct values. And from where you are updating the values? If you are getting values before updating shared preferences, it will definitely give old values.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Instead of using `edit.commit();`, you should use `edit.apply();`. **Apply** will update the preference object instantly and will save the new values *asynchronously*, so allowing you to read the latest values.

---

***commit()***

> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
> SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the
> requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
> SharedPreferences.
>
> Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time,
> the last one to call commit wins.
>
> If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from
> your application's main thread, consider using apply() instead.

**apply()**

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
> storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
> SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
> disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on
> this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is
> still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are
> completed as well as the commit itself.
>
> As SharedPreferences instances are singletons within a process, it's
> safe to replace any instance of commit() with apply() if you were
> already ignoring the return value.
>
> You don't need to worry about Android component lifecycles and their
> interaction with apply() writing to disk. The framework makes sure
> in-flight disk writes from apply() complete before switching states.

Comment: While apply() is a good alternative, it does introduce the issue of having to set your min API to 9 (2.3 Gingerbread) which, according to the current stats, knocks out about 30% of all Android devices out there.  I found that commit() works as long as the next time you check it you're creating a new instance of the SharedPreferences object which might not be a difficult code change

Comment: if `apply()` is called asynchronously, why do I read the newest value if this code? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62637e408baf273a7bc43754422c3739

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev "apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures." When you read from the shared preferences immediately after you put a value and apply it, it tells you the value from memory and not the storage.

Answer (score 2):

Well, even if my answer came 3 years after the question, I hope it will help. The problem don't seem to came from commit or apply but from the code structure.

Let's explain: on a smartphone, you run an APP but you don't quit the APP as we do on computers.
This mean when you come back to the menu of the smartphone, the APP is still "running". When you "click" again on the APP icon, you don't re-run the APP but just awake it. 
In juned code, we can see he calls getDefaultSharedPreferences inside his Create function.

So he calls getDefaultSharedPreferences when he runs first time the APP. But when he sets the APP on background and then awakes the APP, the call is not done.

I've had the same problem:
I check if I have SharedPreference for my APP. If not, I prompt a form to ask value to the user.
If yes, I check the date of the preferences. If too old, I prompt the form.
After the form, I save the preferences with the current date.
What I noticed is that the test about the existence of the SharedPreference (which was set at the same location than the one of juned) was done only at first run of the APP but not when I awake the APP. This mean that I was unable to check the time limite of my SharedPreferences!

How to solve that?
Just add:

```
          @Override
          public void onResume(){
          super.onResume();
         // And put the SharedPreferences test here
          }
```

This code will be called at first run of the APP but also each time the user awake it.

Answer (score 1):

hope it will help you..

```
SharedPreferences mypref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditr = mypref.edit();
prefsEditr.putString("Userid", UserId);
prefsEditr.commit();


String task1 = mypref.getString("Userid", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SharedPreferences edit = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = edit.edit();
editor.putString(Settings.PREF_USERNAME + "", txtuser);
editor.putString(Settings.PREF_PASSWORD + "", entered_name);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this,**

```
public SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
editor.putString(Settings.PREF_USERNAME+"", txtuser);
editor.putString(Settings.PREF_PASSWORD+"", entered_name);
editor.apply()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
public SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
editor.putString(Settings.PREF_USERNAME+"", txtuser);
editor.putString(Settings.PREF_PASSWORD+"", entered_name);
editor.commit();
```