# Accessing SharedPreference not working in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities. In the first activity, I'm putting a String into a shared preference. I then log the getString and I see that it shows up. I then move onto the second activity, and I Toast the getString and I get the default value that shows up.

The first activity code:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor pref_editor = mcontext.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
SharedPreferences pref = mcontext.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref_editor.putString("test", "It works!").commit();
Log.d("XXX", pref.getString("test", "ERRRROR"));
```

The second activity code:

```
SharedPreferences pref = mcontext.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String current = pref.getString("test", "ERROR");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), current,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Any idea why I'm getting the default value of "ERROR" when I toast?

Comment: Does the log print out ok?

Comment: It works for me. Only thing different is my `Context`s are each Activity instances.

Comment: What is the return value of `commit()`?

Comment: Tried with `getApplicationContext()` too and again, no problems. I'd suggest cleaning the project, it might do _something_. Also clear your app's data from your test device.

Comment: Uninstalled the app, and ran it again. Now it works. Ugh. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, at least it works now :-)

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer, I can mark you as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:-

```
SharedPreferences pref = mcontext.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor pref_editor = pref.edit();
pref_editor.putString("test", "It works!")
pref_editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling commit on the editor.  The changes are batched and not written to disk until commit is called.

Comment: OP is calling coomit see `pref_editor.putString("test", "It works!").commit();`

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10186553/838023)  Have you tried apply()?