# shared preference not similar

Tags: android, storage, sharedpreferences

I have two onclick actions that modifies a shared preference file :

```
int value = counters.getInt("wcounter", 0);
wcounter = value;
wcounter++;
Editor editor = counters.edit();
editor.putInt("wcounter", wcounter);
editor.commit();
```

and

```
int value = counters.getInt("wcounter", 0);
wcounter = value;
wcounter--;
Editor editor = counters.edit();
editor.putInt("wcounter", wcounter);
editor.commit();
```

but when the first one is re executed it takes it's old value.

Comment: Not sure but instead of using `editor.commit();`, try using [editor.apply();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186215/sharedpreferences-value-is-not-updated

Comment: yes but it requires a level of APU of at least 9 while I try to work with 7...

Comment: okay. But just curious that it did work or not?

Comment: no it didin't change a thing...

Comment: okay. So, in start first one take value `1` and saves it. Then if  you keep pressing the add button it is giving just `1` again and again? Also can you show where are you declaring the SharedPreference ?

Comment: no when the upper one is clicked it increments correctly (for exemple to 20) then if the lower one is clicked it decrements (for exemple to 10) but when the upper one is clicked again it starts to increments from 20 where it should do it from 10.
this is how i first declare it 'final SharedPreferences counters = getSharedPreferences("counters", 0);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my bad, I had a double function that was doing the same thing except the second one was not writing it to the file...
Thanks everybody for your help