# SharedPreferences always get default value in my existing app but when created new app its ok

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

SharedPreferences doesn't work correct in one existing apps. I tried many different ways but still not working. Always get default values app start again.

- It's working when I use same code in created new app.
- It's working all of other existing apps.

Do you know why?

```
    String default_user = "Default_User";
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("TEST_SHAREDPREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String user = pref.getString("user", default_user);
    Log.d("SHARED CHECK", user);
    if (user.equals(default_user)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
        edit.putString("user", "new_user");
        boolean ok = edit.commit();
        user = pref.getString("user", default_user);
        Log.d("SHARED WRITE", user);
        Toast.makeText(this, user + " Save process: " + ok, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Log.d("SHARED READ", user);
        Toast.makeText(this, "READ SharedPrefs: " + user, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**EDIT:** log results

that block always return this for which is incorrect app and I don't know why

```
    //first run
    SHARED CHECK Default_User
    SHARED WRITE new_user

    //each time after first
    SHARED CHECK Default_User
    SHARED WRITE new_user
```

That block always return this for which are all apps

```
    //first run
    SHARED CHECK Default_User
    SHARED WRITE new_user

    //each time after first
    SHARED CHECK new_user
    SHARED READ new_user
```

Comment: did you check that data write successfully

Comment: xml file created in data/data/appfolder/shared_prefs for all apps

Comment: What you want? Please explain .

Comment: Probably not relevant, but your code says it should be logging Default_User but your output shows you logging default_user.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani Shared preferences doesn't work for one app. I need answer why would be? 

I tried many different way again and again but always return default value even xml file created correctly in shared_prefs folder. Checked xml files values correct until when I run again. 
At this time, return default value again!

Comment: This problem is strange. I would check if you override or delete keys or the entire preference file. To do this grep your project for "user" and for "TEST_SHAREDPREF" if those are your real keys. I suspect that your preferences are reset by some code. Search also for `.delete()` calls. Since this can get chatty feel free to [ping me here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132).

Comment: Did you try *PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);*?

Comment: Is there any permission difference between the working and not working app?

Comment: @rekire, tried check that and I found nothing.

Comment: @JJ86 yes I did. I got same result.

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli no there isn't. Files and permission checked.

Comment: Try running `adb shell run-as "your.package.name" ls shared_prefrences` and read the file (with the `cat` command) which contains `TEST_SHAREDPREF` in name. Can you confirm that after the commit method the value is in that file?

Comment: checked that with file explorer. file and content is ok.
When run again I saw file still there is but result always same with default of getSting.

Comment: This might sound utterly stupid but maybe this is happening because the contents are ever so slightly different? Try using equalsIgnoreCase() instead of the equals() and see if that works!!??

Comment: What device the code fails on? This might be a bug of OS. (There were some reported for Android)

Comment: Can you post the source code of that app to Github or Google Drive so that we can check more? If not, please set breakpoint at `public String getString(String key, @Nullable String defValue) {
        synchronized (this) {
            awaitLoadedLocked();
            String v = (String)mMap.get(key);
            return v != null ? v : defValue;
        }
    }` inside `SharedPreferencesImpl` class and debug

Comment: Perhaps in that app, you set default_user somewhere?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186215/sharedpreferences-value-is-not-updated?lq=1)? I'm guessing it might be of help, giving the fact that your question did not specify a contextual usage.

Comment: @Gregory genymotion, samsung, general mobile and discovery devices are using for test.

Comment: @BNK I can't share sorry. Replaced "email" to "default_user" for this question. I tried many different string and all of them get same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved that problem.
A method was added by one of other developers.
All files under data/data/packageName folder except libs folder were being deleted by this method.
I think they tried delete cache folder.

Removed this method and it solved.

Comment: may i know that what is the method name ?

Answer (score 10):

When you call `apply()` or `commit()` the changes are first saved to the app's memory cache and then Android attempts to write those changes onto the disk. What is happening here is that your `commit()` call is failing on the disk but the changes are still made to the app's memory cache, as is visible in the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java).

It is not enough to read the value from the SharedPreferences as that value might not reflect the true value that is on the disk but only that stored in the memory cache.

What you are failing to do is to check the boolean value returned from the `commit()` call, it is probably false for your problematic case. You could retry the `commit()` call a couple of times if false is returned.

Comment: thank you for your answer but same code working for all apps existing or new. That block not working for just one app.

Answer (score 7):

Just use below method and check.

Create one `Java` class **AppTypeDetails.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class AppTypeDetails {

    private SharedPreferences sh;

    private AppTypeDetails() {
    }
    private AppTypeDetails(Context mContext) {
        sh = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    }
    private static AppTypeDetails instance = null;
    public synchronized static AppTypeDetails getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppTypeDetails(mContext);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // get user status
    public String getUser() {
        return sh.getString("user", "");
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        sh.edit().putString("user", user).commit();
    }

    // Clear All Data
    public void clear() {
        sh.edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

Now **Set** value to `SharedPreferences`.

```
AppTypeDetails.getInstance(MainActivity.this).setUser(<user name>);
```

**Get** Value form `SharedPreferences`.

```
String userName = AppTypeDetails.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getUser();
```

Now do any thing with the userName.

Always check

```
if(userName.trim().isEmpty())
{
    // Do anything here.
}
```

because In `SharedPreferences` we set user name blank ("")

or

you can set user name null in `SharedPreferences` then you need check

```
if(userName != null){
    //do anything here
}
```

For **clear** data from `SharedPreferences`.

```
AppTypeDetails.getInstance(MainActivity.this).setUser("");
```

or

```
AppTypeDetails.getInstance(MainActivity.this).clear();
```

Comment: What’s the point of this class? I mean, PreferenceManager is already acting [this way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java#PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences%28%29) more or less.

Comment: I know but using this way you can manage SharedPreferences properly.

Comment: @chirag-savsani, I was very busy for all day. I will check that solution tomorrow. Please give me a day. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani it has same result :\

Comment: Just tell me your whole scenarios.  From begining to end. I mean when you store data, retrive data and clear data from shared preferences.

Comment: I just try make a auto-login. Actually it has been working correctly until last month. It stopped work and never work again. All apps ok. That block is my test code for checking shared preferences working.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you could try is to get a new `SharedPreference` instance after committing and see what happens:

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
String user = pref.getString("user", default_user);
if (user.equals(default_user)) {
    pref.edit().putString("user", "new_user").commit();
    SharedPreferences newPref = this.getSharedPreferences("test", MODE_PRIVATE);
    user = newPref.getString("user", default_user);
}
```

Your editor is committing a new preference map into disk, but it is possible that the old `SharedPreference` instance is not notified of the change.

Comment: I will check your suggestion but remember that code block is fine.

Answer (score 4):

> Instead of using `edit.commit();`, you should use `edit.apply();`. **Apply**
>   **will update the preference object instantly** and will save the new
>   values asynchronously, so allowing you to read the latest values.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186215/sharedpreferences-value-is-not-updated) - Also read detailed difference between `commit()` and `apply()` in this SO Post.

The "Source" post referenced above also states pretty much the same problem and switching to `apply()` seems to have resolved the issue there.

**Problem statement in the referenced post:**

> The problem is that when I am accessing this values, it is not
>   returning updated values, it gives me a value of SharedPreferences.
>
> **But when I am confirming the data in XML file ,the data updated in
>   that.**

*PS: And the reason that the same code block is not working on this one app and working on all other apps could also be that you are either using the block at different places or updating the value somewhere else too.*

Answer (score 4):

Your code is right, the code works on any app very well, looks like that in some part of your app the shared preferences are been modified, the only way to find a solution is review all your code, because if this problem only happens on one app, it's somewhere on your app that the shared preferences are been modified, for good practices, you should have only one file class for the management of your preferences on that way you can comment or find usage for a method and you can find where  the shared preferences was been modified.

BTW the best way to store an user, password, or any account info is using [Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

For good practices you can see this sample PreferenceHelper class.

```
public class PreferencesHelper {

public static final String DEFAULT_STRING_VALUE = "default_value";

/**
 * Returns Editor to modify values of SharedPreferences
 * @param context Application context
 * @return editor instance
 */
private static Editor getEditor(Context context){
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}

/**
 * Returns SharedPreferences object
 * @param context Application context
 * @return shared preferences instance
 */
private static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context){
    String name = "YourAppPreferences";
    return context.getSharedPreferences(name,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

/**
 * Save a string on SharedPreferences
 * @param tag tag
 * @param value value
 * @param context Application context
 */
public static void putString(String tag, String value, Context context) {
    Editor editor = getEditor(context);
    editor.putString(tag, value);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Get a string value from SharedPreferences
 * @param tag tag
 * @param context Application context
 * @return String value
 */
public static String getString(String tag, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(tag, DEFAULT_STRING_VALUE);
}}
```

Comment: Thank your for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I used the below code pattern in one of my app and I always get the latest value stored in SharedPreferences. Below is the edited version for your problem:

```
public class AppPreference
        implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final String USER         = "User";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USER = "Default_User";

    private Context mContext;
    private String mDefaultUser;

    private SharedPreferences mPref;
    private static AppPreference mInstance;

    /**
     * hide it.
     */
    private AppPreference(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        mPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        reloadPreferences();
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @return single instance of shared preferences.
     */
    public static AppPreference getInstance(Context context) {
        return mInstance == null ?
                (mInstance = new AppPreference(context)) :
                mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return value of default user
     */
    public String getDefaultUser() {
        return mDefaultUser;
    }

    /**
     * Set value for default user
     */
    public void setDefaultUser(String user) {
        mDefaultUser = user;
        mPref.edit().putString(USER, mDefaultUser).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Reloads all values if preference values are changed.
     */
    private void reloadPreferences() {
        mDefaultUser = mPref.getString(USER, DEFAULT_USER);
        // reload all your preferences value here
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        reloadPreferences();
    }
}
```

You can **set** the value as below in your activity:

```
AppPreference.getInstance(this).setDefaultUser("user_value");
```

To **get** the updated value for saved user, use below code:

```
String user = AppPreference.getInstance(this).getDefaultUser();
```

Hope this solution will fix the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

For saving and retrieving data from SharedPrefrence create a util type methods in your Utility class:

Below I have given code snippet for both the methods i.e for saving and retrieving SharedPrefrence data:

```
   public class Utility {        

    public static void putStringValueInSharedPreference(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
    }


    public static String getStringSharedPreference(Context context, String param) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(param, "");
   }
}
```

Now you just need to call Utility.putStringValueInSharedPreference(Activity_Context,KEY,VALUE); to put data in prefrence and Utility.getStringSharedPreference(Activity_Context,KEY); to get value from prefrence.
This methodology reduces chances of error; May this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend controlling your preference check with another preference value.

```
String user = pref.getString("user", default_user);
```

In your preference check:

```
String getStatus = pref.getString("register", "nil");

if (getStatus.equals("true")) {
    // move on code stuff
}
else{
    // ask for preferences
}
```

In the part where the preference is added.

```
edit.putString("user", "new_user");
editor.putString("register", "true");
edit.commit;
```

Comment: Please don't ever store booleans as strings. SharedPreferences has `putBoolean()` and `getBoolean()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is correct or not, but you can implement a Shared preference change listener and you can log in that and check if the shared preference is not called again in any other class, which is again setting the value to Default user.

I Mean you got to make sure that there is no other code resetting the value of user.

Answer (score 1):

The code itself looks fine and you say it works in other apps. Since you have confirmed the XML file gets properly created, the only remaining option is that something happens to the file before you read it during app launch. If there is no other code in the app that handles any shared preferences, then something must wipe the file during the launch.

You should take careful look at launch configuration of this particular app and compare to other apps where this is working. Maybe there is some option that wipes user data when app is started. I know there is such an option at least for emulator (in Eclipse), but I am not sure if you are running this in emulator or device.

You should also try launching the app directly from the device instead of IDE. This tells if the problem is in the app itself or IDE configuration. And try moving this from onCreate (where I presume this is) to onResume and compare does it work when you resume to the app versus when you completely restart it.

Comment: Generally I used to emulator. If I had any problem I tried different phones like that.