# Android Studio: SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have one Textbox in Main activity and one edit textbox in Create Activity. I used the create activity to generate my text to the textbox in main activity. This part works.

However, when i switched back to create activity, the text in texbox in main activity is gone.

I want to save the text in textbox even after switching activities

Comment: For this have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676947/sharedpreferences-always-get-default-value-in-my-existing-app-but-when-created-n/34722133#34722133 user class for `SharedPreference` is best practise.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save the value of your `String` across the activities.

- In MainActivity, **read** from the `SharedPreferences`. [Get the String value](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) from the `SharedPreferences` (default value is set to be the `String` "Default Value") and set that value to the `TextView`.

  ```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
  // read from SharedPreferences
  // get the string value using the key "string" set when writing to the shared preferences
  // return string default otherwise
  String string = sharedPreferences.getString("string", "Default Value");

  // get the TextView
  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  // setText on TextView
  textView.setText(string);
  ```
- In CreateActivity, **write** to the `SharedPreferences`. In the lifecycle method `onPause()` of your activity, write to the `SharedPreferences` by getting the value from the `EditText` using the `getText()` method.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      // write to SharedPreferences with edit
      getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
              .putString("string", editText.getText().toString())
              .apply();
  }
  ```

*Quick note:* When getting `SharedPreferences` using `getSharedPreferences()`, be sure to use the same name - in our case `"sharedPrefs"`.

Tried and tested just now - so feel free to ask questions!

Answer (score -1):

There are some project for you:
1.Make the text as cache, and when you switch to main activity, you take the text from cache and set text to the textbox, you can use SharePrefrence or DiskCache to save the cache
2.make main activity Single, like set the launchMode="singleTask" in AndroidManifest.xml ,you should make that main activity would not be finish when you switch to create activity
There are my idea, you can try, good luck!