# SharedPrefereces Not able to save Values

Tags: android

Iam not able to store values in shared prefernces.As soon as the activity is closed the no value remains saved.  On starting the activity again the ids used to store and fetch data have null values.
Heres is my code.i am not attaching the layout as they will be of no significance.
As I am new to android.There might be some simple thing i a missing.Please help

```
    public class enter_db extends AppCompatActivity
    {
    String field;
    EditText usrtext,idtxt,bananatxt,coconuttxt,timbertxt,bambootxt,goldtxt,garage1txt,garage2txt,garage3txt,garage4txt,garage5txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.db_entry);
    usrtext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    idtxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserID);
    bananatxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.banana_count);
    coconuttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.coconut_count);
    bambootxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.banana_count);
    timbertxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Timber_count);
    goldtxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.gold_count);
    garage1txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.garage_1);
    garage2txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.garage_2);
    garage3txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.garage_3);
    garage4txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.garage_4);
    garage5txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.garage_5);
    SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    if(pref.getString("Username",null)!="")
    {
    field=pref.getString("Username",null);
        usrtext.setHint("Username"+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("UserID",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("UserID",null);
        idtxt.setHint("UserID: "+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Banana",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Banana",null);
        bananatxt.setHint("Banana: "+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Coconut",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Coconut",null);
        coconuttxt.setHint("Cococnut: "+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Timber",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Timber",null);
        timbertxt.setHint("Timber: "+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Bamboo",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Bamboo",null);
        bambootxt.setHint("Bamboo"+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Gold",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Gold",null);
        goldtxt.setHint("Gold: "+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Garage1",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Garage1",null);
        garage1txt.setHint("Garage1 :"+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Garage2",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Garage2",null);
        garage2txt.setHint("Garage2 :"+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Garage3",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Garage3",null);
        garage3txt.setHint("Garage3 :"+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Garage4",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Garage4",null);
        garage4txt.setHint("Garage4 :"+field);
    }
    if(pref.getString("Garage5",null)!=null)
    {
        field=pref.getString("Garage5",null);
        garage5txt.setHint("Garage5 :"+field);
    }

    editor.putString("Username",usrtext.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("UserID",idtxt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Banana",bananatxt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Coconut",coconuttxt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Timber",timbertxt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Bamboo",bambootxt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Gold",goldtxt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Garage1",garage1txt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Garage2",garage2txt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Garage3",garage3txt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Garage4",garage4txt.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Garage5",garage5txt.getText().toString());
    ImageButton ok=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Start new list activity
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            editor.apply();
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Garage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: try to change editor.putString("Garage4",garage4txt.getText().toString()).apply(); in every line

Comment: use `.commit()` or `.apply()` to save the changes to sharedprefrence

Comment: did it when the "ok" button is clicked

Comment: Move all the `editor.putString()` calls to inside `onClick()`, before `editor.apply();`.

Comment: Look this example, In this example I use  `SharedPrefrence` using class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676947/sharedpreferences-always-get-default-value-in-my-existing-app-but-when-created-n/34722133#34722133

Comment: It worked. Thanks for help @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

U missed the apply() / commit() to save chanegs.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Elena");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.apply(); // editor.commit()
```

apply() is faster and async while commit() is synchronous.

Comment: did it when the "ok" button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
 editor.putString("Garage5",garage5txt.getText().toString());
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: Please update your answer with a brief explanation to improve the quality of it.

Answer (score 0):

Save value in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings =getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(key, value);
    editor. putBoolean(key, value);
            editor.commit();
```

get value from shared preferences:

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppName", 0);
            String value=settings.getString(key, ""); 
    boolean value=settings.getBoolean(key,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As in above code you are not saving value of edit text in shared preference on button click,try this way

`ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // Start new list     activity  public void onClick(View v)  {      editor.putString("Username",usrtext.getText().toString());  editor.putString("UserID",idtxt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Banana",bananatxt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Coconut",coconuttxt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Timber",timbertxt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Bamboo",bambootxt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Gold",goldtxt.getText().toString());        editor.putString("Garage1",garage1txt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Garage2",garage2txt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Garage3",garage3txt.getText().toString());  editor.putString("Garage4",garage4txt.getText().toString());      editor.putString("Garage5",garage5txt.getText().toString());   editor.apply();  Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Garage.class);  startActivity(i);  } });`